# API redirect always on "User Already Exists", SQlite3

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlite

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']
        db = sqlite3.connect("BucketList.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
        cursor.execute("Select * from tbl_user where user_username = ?", (_email, ))
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        if data:
            return render_template('error.html',error = 'User Already Exists.')
        else:
            if not data:
                cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name, user_username, user_password)
                        VALUES(?,?,?)''', (_name, _email, _hashed_password))  
                db.commit()
        return render_template('regok.html',regok = 'User created successfully !')
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
    finally:
         db.close()
```

If I try to register and the user already exists, I get "User already exists' which is ok, but when I try to register and the user does not exists, I have the same redirect on "User already exist" and the user is created in the database, and I can log in.

How can fix it? Example:
User exists = redirect on User exists
User does not exists - redirect on User create success.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that if a user doesn't exist, you still get the error message "User Already Exists" but that user is then added to the database. If you are getting "User Already Exists" then the `insert` statement shouldn't be executing. Your problem is a little confusing.

Comment: hmm, thx for your answer, but how i can made check for emails , exists or not exists in db, and after that create user?